# Conditionally changing background color in rails according to order status

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, dynamic

I'm trying to change the background of a view depending on whether a user saved an order or not. So a menu item will be highlighted when the user has already saved an order, and not highlighted when he has not.

One solution is to create two partials, and to render each conditionally based on the user action.

But it seems overkill to re-render an entire partial, and bad form in general. What is the best way to change the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two layouts for this. Put a .highlight class on the menu item when the save is successful, and have the css for the .highlight class do what you want.

Comment: After I bunch of faffing around I figured out the details of what you meant - it's quite straightforward and smooth. Thank you!

Comment: It was - I am just new and so it takes me practice to process. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if in the controller and use
`render :layout => 'special_layout'`
to change the layout depending on the if branch.

Take a look at [This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)